# Quadratic Residues, $y^2 \equiv q \bmod p,$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Given $p$, $q$ and
$$
y^2 \equiv q \bmod p,
$$
how to solve for the values of $y$?

I can do it manually with small numbers, but with large numbers is not applicable, since there is a mathematical way, could you please help  me in this?

Comment: Law of Quadratic Reciprocity aids in computing it by reducing it to calculation with smaller numbers. If you just started quadratic congruences,  you have to  wait until you learn that. Do not worry with large numbers it is difficult for experts too calculating this without using Reciprocity Law.

Comment: There's not really a good way.  If $p$ is prime, you can use the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli–Shanks_algorithm.  In the olden days we had tables of primitive roots, which could help.

Comment: yes p,q are primes

Comment: @B.Goddard What I don't understand [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm#Core_ideas) is that they talk of $R = n^{(Q+1)/2}$ whereas $R^2 = n \ne 1$  implies $R$ isn't a power of $n$..

Comment: I think $R$ is just a first guess.  This algorithm supposedly mimics Newton's method for approximating roots.  I confess, I've never dissected things to see the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the quadratic residue articles in Number theory books. Or you can simply google it. 
Here is some useful links . 
[1](https://brilliant.org/wiki/quadratic-residues/)[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)

Comment: [Tonelli–Shanks_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) seems to be the answer.